# connect Android acra lib Exception report to php

Tags: android, debugging, exception

I recently use [www.acra.ch Exception Report library](http://acra.ch).

in acra website pointed to "you can code your own!" (manager) so i want to use a php file to insert data in database , but i can't found any sample PHP Script to get posted values , and continue my job !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest script I use. It will dump all POST data into a text file named by the date it occurred:

```
<?php
// Outputs all POST parameters to a text file. The file name is the date_time of the report reception
    $fileName = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.txt';
    $file = fopen($fileName,'w') or die('Could not create report file: ' . $fileName);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $reportLine = $key." = ".$value."\n";
        fwrite($file, $reportLine) or die ('Could not write to report file ' . $reportLine);
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

I'm about 98.7% sure this is the PHP script they supply on ACRA's help website (can't remember where I initially found this).

Take a look at the important stuff:

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $reportLine = $key." = ".$value."\n";
        fwrite($file, $reportLine) or die ('Could not write to report file ' . $reportLine);
    }
```

If you want to somehow map that to a database, the above for-each loop is how you'll be able to get the key-value pairs. From there, you should be able to determine what you want to actually save.